# Error emitted when creating a connection between GCP Bigquery and Cloud SQL (Mysql 5.7) using bq command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I want to create a connection between Bigquery and Cloud SQL(MySQL 5.7)　in a **newly created project** ! (not in existing project, I can create the connection in existing project with no problem)

This is the command I used

```
bq mk --connection --connection_type='CLOUD_SQL' --properties='{"instanceId":"<PROJECT ID>:<REGION>:<MYSQL INSTANCE>","database":"<MY DATABASE>","type":"MYSQL"}' --connection_credential='{"username":"root", "password":"<PASSWORD>"}' --project_id=<PROJECT ID> --location=<REGION> <MYSQL INSTANCE>
```

but I got the error like below

```
BigQuery error in mk operation: Access Denied: URI:  services/bigqueryconnection.googleapis.com/projects/<PROJECT ID>:
APPLICATION_ERROR;google.api.serviceconsumermanagement.v1beta1/ServiceConsumerManagerV1Beta1.GenerateServiceIdentity;Permission denied to generate service identity for service
[bigqueryconnection.googleapis.com]
Details: [{
IAM{policy: 'serviceconsumermanagement_consumers-/000000555846b828/bigqueryconnection.googleapis.com/000000b742218216' resource: 'services/bigqueryconnection.googleapis.com/consumers/<PROJECT ID>'
permission: 'serviceconsumermanagement.consumers.generateServiceAccount'}
allowed: false auditlog: false cloudaudit: false
}]

...
...
```

After a lot of research, I think the problem is maybe I don't have a service acccount like this with a role called `BigQuery Connection Service agent`. because I have this kind of service account in another project.

```
service-<project id>@gcp-sa-bigqueryconnection.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I don't really know how this service account being created, maybe by enabling the Bigquery Connection API service, I will have a service account like above being created.

Although the bigquery Connection API has already being enabled, I disalbed it then enabled it again. but the service account still not being created.

Does anyone has any idea about this problem ? Thank you so much.

update:

Sorry I forgot to say I already have the bigquery Admin/bigquery connection admin/cloud sql admin permissions

Answer (score 0):

You need grant `bigquery.admin` access. Document [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#bq)

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project_id \
--member group/user:address \
--role roles/bigquery.admin
```

**Example:**

```
$ bq mk --connection --connection_type='CLOUD_SQL' --properties='{"instanceId":"data-lab:us-east1:instance-mysql","database":"information_schema","type":"MYSQL"}' --connection_credential='{"username":"root", "password":"*****"}' --project_id=data-lab --location=us MyExternalSQL
Connection 906721254566.us.MyExternalSQL successfully created
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the BigQuery Connection API, a service account should be automatically created on your behalf with the following roles:

```
    cloudsql.client
    logging.logWriter
    metrics.metricWriter
```

and to create and maintain a connection resource, user must have the bigquery.admin predefined role as @Soumendra mentioned.

Check Document [Cloud SQL federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#service_account)

I enabled the API, but a service account wasn't created.

Check Document  [BigQuery Connection API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bigqueryconnection#setting_up_authentication) for creating that service account.

Once that is done, try connecting.

Comment: do you mean `bigquery connection services agent` service account ? but it seems like the service account is not being created anymore in my newly created gcp project.